# Tinymce to submit form on blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to submit the form from where Tinymce is in on blur event but this doesn't seem to work.

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea.html',
            menubar:false,
            force_br_newlines : true,
            force_p_newlines : false,
            resize: false,
            setup: function (editor) {

                var val;

                editor.on('focus', function(e) {
                    val = editor.getContent();
                });

                editor.on('blur', function(e) {
                    editor.save();
                    if(val!=editor.getContent()){
                        $(this).submit();
                    }
                });

                editor.on('change', function () {
                    editor.save();
                });

            }
          });
```

I know the mistake is from `$(this).submit();` cause form selector is wrong but I can't figure out how to get to select the form in question. Anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your `<form>` tag look like in your HTML?

Comment: @MichaelFromin Thanks for your comment, managed to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself:

```
var formID = editor.getElement().parentNode.id;
editor.on('blur', function(e) {
    editor.save();
    if(val!=editor.getContent()){
        $('#'+formID).submit();
    }
});
```